# Cannot submit app in AppStore Connect using EAS

Tags: expo, app-store-connect, eas

I am trying to submit my app in appstore using the command:

```
eas submit -p ios --latest --profile development
```

I have generated an app-specific password in my apple account and I have set it as env variable using the command:

```
set EXPO_APPLE_APP_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD="YOUR_APP_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD"
```

where in the YOUR_APP_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD I pasted the generated app-specific password.

I go on with the submit command I mentioned but I get the error:

```
Your Apple ID or app-specific password is incorrect. Verify that you entered them correctly and try again.
```

I have double checked and everything looks fine from the eas.json and app.json. What is causing this and how can I fix it?